# Google Scripts - View Log stuck at "Waiting for logs, please wait..."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run a script for my Google Sheet on Scripts, and a function isn't working properly. I have some loggers in place to check why this is happening, but anytime I try to open the Logs tab, I get this:
[image]
... and it's just stuck there forever.

Has anyone ever had this problem? Any potential fixes? Thanks

EDIT: My executions window looks like so: 
[image]

EDIT 2: Here is the code I'm trying to run, with segment = 1. SPREADSHEETS is just a variable that I'm unfortunately not able to share, but it just contains some import segment information that directs to either 1 or 2.

```
function CopyPasteAllSheets(segment) {



for (x in SPREADSHEETS) {




if (SPREADSHEETS[x].IMPORTSEGMENT != segment) {
  // DRR added app which is redundant to intakeSpreadhseet, but keeps logic more readable
  app.toast('running loop')
console.log("ID: " + SPREADSHEETS[x].SOURCE.ID + "NO MATCH");

} else {




// Logger.log("x: "+ x) // keep commented out


var intakeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEETS[x].INTAKE.ID);
var intakeSheet = intakeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(SPREADSHEETS[x].INTAKE.SHEET); //confirm formatting conventions


// This is functionally equivlent to the above, except we don't have a reference to intakeSpreadsheet anymore

// Access the Spreadsheet and sheet you want to copy the data TO
console.log("ID: "+ SPREADSHEETS[x].SOURCE.ID)
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEETS[x].SOURCE.ID);
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(SPREADSHEETS[x].SOURCE.SHEET);
var sourceStartRow = SPREADSHEETS[x].SOURCE.STARTROW;
var sourceStartCol = SPREADSHEETS[x].SOURCE.STARTCOL;
var sourceRangeCol = SPREADSHEETS[x].SOURCE.ENDCOL - SPREADSHEETS[x].SOURCE.STARTCOL + 1;





// Get the range of the data you want and the range where you want the data to go
    var rowsToCopy = sourceSheet.getLastRow()-sourceStartRow+1; // is +1 too conservative, check...
    var rangeToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceStartRow,sourceStartCol,rowsToCopy, sourceRangeCol); 

    var dataToCopy = rangeToCopy.getValues();

var numRows = rowsToCopy;
var numColumns = sourceRangeCol;
var intakeStartRow = SPREADSHEETS[x].INTAKE.STARTROW;
var intakeStartCol = SPREADSHEETS[x].INTAKE.STARTCOL;
var rangeToPaste = intakeSheet.getRange(intakeStartRow,intakeStartCol, numRows,numColumns); // WAS FORMERLY 1,20, ..,.. ~DRR 7/14
rangeToPaste.setValues(dataToCopy);

  }
}
}
```

Comment: You can find the same information with view/executions.   Yes it's a nuissance but it's better than waiting forever.

Comment: For executions, it's also not showing the logs, even though I do have logger.log present several times in my code. I edited above to show you what my executions window looks like.

Comment: Use `console.log()`

Comment: would console.log() show in executions? Because if so that hasn't worked either.

Comment: I find that some times it takes a while for the logs to appear in the executions as well.  I was just running a new webap and noticed a significant delay in the  view/executions display of the logs. And yes you can use console.log too.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to share your script and we can take a look at it.

Comment: Done, check edit 2, thank you so much

Comment: Well we don't know what segment and we can't know what Spreadsheets is.  So I think it's a waste of my time.

Comment: Hi there @coolyfrost, `console.log()` works and the logs should appear in the `Stack Driver Logs`. Also, your execution might take longer than expected - depending on the calls you are making, so that's why the logs don't show up instantly. A parameter representing the time for the execution should appear next to the execution. Have you tried refreshing the page?

Comment: The `if` condition is `false`>so, the statements inside like `console.log()` is not executed. You can visit view> stackdriver logging

Comment: Can you try to do a `console.log()` right at the beginning of function? Does that show up? @coolyfrost